# Showing a set is $\mu$-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to show that if $B\subset \mathbb R$, $A\subset \mathbb R$, $A$ is $\mu$-measurable, and $\mu^*(S(A,B))=0$, then $B$ is $\mu$-measurable.

Here are the definitions I have to work with (from Rudin's Principles of Analysis):

A set is $\mu$-measurable if it is the union of a countable collection of finitely $\mu$-measurable sets. For example, if $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and each $A_n$ is finitely $\mu$-measurable, then A is $\mu$-measurable. Now, a set $A$ is finitely $\mu$-measurable if there is sequence of elementary sets ${A_n}$ such that $\lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} d(A,A_n)=0$. An elementary set is a union of finitely many bounded intervals of the real line; for example, $[0,1]\cup (1,2)\cup [2,3)\cup (3,2]$ is an elementary set; notice how the bounded intervals may be open, closed, or half open/half closed. Here, $d(A,A_n)=\mu^*(S(A,A_n))$, where $S(A,A_n)=(A-A_N)\cup (A_n-A)$, or the symmetric difference between two sets. Finally, $\mu^*$ is the outer measure of set. Specifically: for any real set E, $\mu^*(E)=\inf(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_n))$, where $\mu$ is any real, additive, non-negative, finite, and regular set function defined over the set of all elementary sets, and where the infimum is taken over all the countable covers of E consisting of open elementary sets. More specifically: a regular set function is function $\mu$ such that for any elementary set $A$ and for any $\epsilon >0$, there exist elementary sets $F$ and $G$ such that $F\subset A\subset G$, $F$ closed and $G$ open, and $\mu(G)-\epsilon \le \mu(A) \le \mu(F)+\epsilon$. And by a countable cover of $E$ consisting of elementary sets I mean $E\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$, where each $E_n$ is an open elementary set.

I tried applying the definitions directly, but that didn't get me anywhere. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $S(\cdot,\cdot)$? Symmetric difference?

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this,
we know $A$, $A\backslash B$ and $B\backslash A$ are all measurable. 
Now observe that 
$$B = (A\cup B\backslash A)\backslash(A\backslash B),$$
the measurability of $B$ is shown from the $\sigma$-algebra structure of measurable sets.